# drupal divide content by tags or cateogries

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tags, drupal-taxonomy

I have strange request to deal with. We have large piece of articles need to be added into drupal as article. Different paragraph within that article is tagged with keywords. 
Now I cant find a way to do so in wysiwyg editor. I can only tag whole article with taxonomy term.
Any direction or suggestion, how can i tag specific paragraph by different keywords within an article.

Answer (score 1):

You have a module called Field Group and it allows you to group some number of field. You can also make those groups repeatable.

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group

Maybe there is some other module doing same thing, not sure about that.

Anyway, you can make groups of 2 fields, one wysiwyg area for one paragraph and other taxonomy reference, for tagging that paragraph. And you can put that group to be multiple (repeatable) so you can unlimited number of groups (paragraphs) per page.
You can also add some other field(s) in that group if they are paragraph related.

Comment: field_group combines fields for display purpose and not the logic. So it wouldn't be possible to filter out result in search based on field grouping.

Comment: Not sure that I get you here, but you can have more than one taxonomy and more than one taxonomy reference in your content type.

Comment: may be i am mistaken... as per module doc "The purpose of this module is to group fields with the intention of wrapping them in a container; not to handle logic on the fields."       doesnt it mean grouping is done for only display purpose here. ?

Comment: It's grouped in back-end. On front-end template dictates how it will be displayed but on back-end you'll initially get fields for first group - wysiwyg editor and tags. Then when you enter values there you'll be able to add another group, and another and another...

Comment: Ok, i have played around with it. It does not Add another set of field whereas you can repeat individual field within the group set. For instance I have a field group for 2 entity reference and one simple date field. All three with unlimited values. Now there are individual "Add another" button for each field instead of whole set. This blog explains as well http://openconcept.ca/blog/mducharme/creating-multiple-value-field-groups-drupal-7